# Error after upgrading Rails to 6.1: uninitialized constant RSpec::Rails::Railtie::SourceAnnotationExtractor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, uninitialized-constant, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Running `rspec` after upgrading Rails results in an uninitialized constant error: `RSpec::Rails::Railtie::SourceAnnotationExtractor`.

The backtrace points to the "rails_helper.rb" file.

I already attempted a `bundle update rspec-rails`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding this question and answer because I didn't find the exact issue or solution when searching StackOverflow.

It turns out that rspec-rails was stuck because rspec wasn't updating (stuck on v 3.6).

The fix:

```
bundle update rspec rspec-rails
```

It was critical to update both gems at once. That finally updated rspec-rails to 5.0.1 and rspec to 3.10.0.

Thanks to this thread for vital information:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1298

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error and this solved it.

I changed the version of the rspec-rails gem in the gemfile according to this list that I found in the README section of the [gem's github repo](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/tree/6-0-maintenance#rspec-rails--):

- rspec-rails 6.x for Rails 6.1 or 7.x.
- rspec-rails 5.x for Rails 5.2
  or 6.x.
- rspec-rails 4.x for Rails from 5.x or 6.x.
- rspec-rails 3.x for Rails earlier than 5.0.
- rspec-rails 1.x for Rails 2.x.

So, in my case, I upgraded to 6.1, so I used: `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 6.0.0'`